# Is it possible to assign to an array from an initializer list?

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment, initializer-list

I am trying to make it possible to assign to an array from an initializer list in C++, if this is possible  how to do it? may be the new versions of C++ needs to achieve it or not?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arrayName_A[5];
    arrayName_A = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout << "\n Starting checker" << '\n';
        cout << "checked: " << arrayName_A[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays aren't assignable (they can't appear on the left-hand side of an assignment).

Comment: Doesn't matter which version of C++ you use.   An array is not assignable.   You can initialise it in the definition (i.e. `int arrayname_A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};` which is not an assignment) and subsequently manipulate elements individually (e.g. in a loop) but not assign the whole array.    A `std::array<int, 5>` (which, not withstanding its name, is a templated class specified in header `<array>` that manages an array, and not an array) can be assigned using initialiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues.

That is you may not write for example

```
int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int b[3] = a;
```

or

```
int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int b[3];

b = a;
```

You may set each element of an array with a value from an initializer list using the range-based for loop as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int arrayName_A[5];
    
    size_t i = 0;
    
    for ( const auto &item :  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } ) arrayName_A[i++] = item;
    
    for ( const auto &item : arrayName_A ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Otherwise use the standard class `std::array` that has the assignment operator. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() 
{
    std::array<int, 5> arrayName_A;
    

    arrayName_A =  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
    // or
    
    arrayName_A =  { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };
    
    for ( const auto &item : arrayName_A ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above that is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible. You either have to intialize the array directly:

```
 int arrayName_A[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

or use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```
std::array<int, 5> arrayName_A;
arrayName_A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the array as soon as you declare it, like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arrayName_A[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout << "\n Starting checker" << '\n';
        cout << "checked: " << arrayName_A[i] << '\n';

        cout << "\n Starting checker" << '\n';
        cout << "checked: " << arrayName_A[i] << '\n';

        cout << "\n Starting checker" << '\n';
        cout << "checked: " << arrayName_A[i] << '\n';

        cout << "\n Starting checker" << '\n';
        cout << "checked: " << arrayName_A[i] << '\n';

        cout << "\n Starting checker" << '\n';
        cout << "checked: " << arrayName_A[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this but the goal is to Initialize it from the initializer list